# Convert 8 digit to DATETIME

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I am working with SQL Server and have time in numeric format e.g. `63415620`.

How can I convert it into `datetime` format?

Comment: What time is that?

Comment: Most integer representations of date+time are UNIX-time values, but `63415620` is not a UNIX-time value (either in seconds or milliseconds). So we need more details.

Comment: All databases have date types, with indexing and analytics support. Use the *correct* type to store dates. Convert text or integer representation to dates while loading instead of trying to recover the data after the fact. Is that number affected by DST? Which timezone? Using date types is far more portable than storing a number with unknown meaning or precision too.

Comment: it is representing time in our DB, but i am not create the so i need to figured out how is it represented, or how i should convert it to date.

Comment: @PavelProkop then you have a serious database design bug. If *you* can't guess what that is, how can others? Why don't you use a `date` or `datetime2` or `datetimeoffset` ?

Comment: i have just joined new company and this is old db where is it and they need some changes to do.

Comment: @PavelProkop what date is this supposed to be? Assuming seconds and an epoch starting at 1970-01-01 it's `1972-01-04 23:27:00`. Does that make sense? If it does, you should add calculated columns that convert this number to proper dates, preferably `datetime2(0)`

Comment: @PavelProkop Sql Server never needed such tricks. It always had `datetime`, and since 2005 (if not 2000) it has `date`, `datetime2` and `datetimeoffset`. Most likely a client application stores the data as old-style Unix timestamps for some reason.

Comment: 2008 introduced the new date and time data types, @PanagiotisKanavos . 2005 was the `MAX` data types, if I recall correctly, which promptly deprecated the `text` and `image` data types in 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After multiple guesses, I would suggest that it is the number of minutes after `1900-01-01`. *Why* your company has chosen that as their epoch style is beyond me; it is not standard.

If you try all the below:

```sql
SELECT DATEADD(MILLISECOND,63415620,'19700101'),
       DATEADD(SECOND,63415620,'19700101'),
       DATEADD(MINUTE,63415620,'19700101'),
       DATEADD(MILLISECOND,63415620,'19000101'),
       DATEADD(SECOND,63415620,'19000101'),
       DATEADD(MINUTE,63415620,'19000101');
```

The last (`DATEADD(MINUTE,63415620,'19000101')`) returns `2020-07-28 15:00:00`, which is the only time that seems appropriate.

Comment: I suggest that the company documents their data, @PavelProkop . Considering that the database is old, it should already have a lot of documentation already though...

Comment: @Larnu applications over 20 years old may have used unix timestamps to allow them to work with obsolete or very old databases on Unix or other obsolete OSs that didn't really have date support (DB2 file-based for example), perhaps even file-based databases like dBase or Clipper. I remember finding out that Unicenter TNG stored dates as Unix timestamps in an *Oracle* database in 2010. The arrogant TNG consultant tried to persuade me this was a Sql Server problem somehow, that "others" treated timestamps just fine  .....

Comment: @Larnu luckily, that database was used to store only local incidents of a multi-national telco. Imagine trying to store different timezones as Unix timestamps, never mind different DST rules  ...

Comment: I'm not saying that storing data as an epoch is non-standard, but that using the numbers of minutes since `1900-01-01` isn't standard, @PanagiotisKanavos . UNIX uses seconds or milliseconds since `1970-01-01` for example.

Comment: @Larnu I was preparing to post a quip about how some common conventions are due to laziness but then I remembered a lecture by a member of IBM's early SQL team where he said that the DB2 team wanted to standardise `WHERE 2=field` to make parsing easier. The SQL team wasn't thrilled

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I struggle to imagine how `2=field` makes parsing easier - because they'd still need to support arbitrary predicate expressions anyway...

Comment: @Dai have you tried Go, the language? Where an array is defined as [2]string ? Anyway, the lecturer [was this guy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hugh_Darwen) and the time he referred to was in the late 1970s. I got the specific product wrong though. I remember him telling us that the relational model and SQL were *not* related at all - SQL was created by a different team as a language for business people, that IBM marketing slapped on its relational database products. Which shouldn't sound so weird when us modern humans think that XML, JSON or YAML are good as languages

Comment: @Dai most problems people associate with the relational model are really SQL problems, that *non*relational language. So much so that CJ Date (the inventor of the relational model) and Hugh Darwen highlighted those problems and proposed solutions in [The Third Manifesto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Third_Manifesto).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yeah, I developed a web-service backend for an Angular for a Redis-like database using Go a few years ago - I wasn't a fan :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the integer values are epoch timestamps (that is, the number of seconds elapsed since January 1st, 1970), you can turn it to a `datetime` with the following expression:

```
dateadd(second, my_integer_column, '19700101')
```